# Duplicate function name in Class View when defined in a namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 4.
I've defined a couple functions in my header file:

```
class CFileReader;
class CFileWriter;

namespace FileFixer
{
    bool makeFixedFileName ( const wchar_t* inFile , wchar_t* outFile , size_t maxLen );
    bool fixFile ( CFileReader& fileReader , CFileWriter& fileWriter );
}
```

And in the source file:

```
#include "FileReader.h"
#include "FileWriter.h"

namespace FileFixer
{
    bool makeFixedFileName ( const wchar_t* inFile , wchar_t* outFile , size_t maxLen )
    {
        // Do something here ...
        return true;
    }
    bool fixFile ( CFileReader& fileReader , CFileWriter& fileWriter )
    {
        // Do something more here ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the Class View pane the functions name are repeated, but the first name got a small white arrow behind the 3d purple box icon like this:

[image]

If I right click on both of them the menu is the same, if I double click also the behaviour is identical. I didn't find anything on the online help [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx). What is this for?

Comment: @Ajay, could you please underline where in the existing question is reported the same my problem?

Comment: Apologies. I was probably marking other post as duplicate, and marked this one.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it should hardly matter to you. But I see the arrow in my code base for the functions implemented outside the class-declaration (i.e. into implementation file). All inline methods are shown without the arrow symbol. 
I am not sure why they are duplicated in your case. May be namespace implementation has something to do.

But, again - why does it matter?

Comment: Is an interestinq questo to me for mainly tow reasons: I'm learning everyday how VS2013 works so I would like to know how much I can about this IDE and maybe this information (the white arrow) could be usefull ... if only I know why is there!!! And secondly and more important, if is not necessary and is a bug is quite annoyng then !!! My project is bigger then two inline functions. I have tons of duplicated names. If is a bug I will report it to Microsoft.

Comment: VS has trillions of other features to look for. This should on lowest priority to learn. Intellisense, remote debugging, conditional breakpoints, multiple language debugging.. many features. Learn them! :)

Comment: Well that's what I'm doing, since Visual Studio 97 and I already know enough about all the other featurs so that's why I have time to investigate deeper in details that probably they looks "insignificant".